# The problem with importing custom modules in Python

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

There is a strange problem. I have two Jupyter Notebooks. One of them is located in **the same directory as the module** I'm going to import. Another notebook - in another dir. As for the notebook in the same dir, everything works pretty good. But working with another makes lots of troubles.

Well, the import starts with adding the package to PYTHONPATH using sys.append(dir). After this **main_module.py** can be imported easily.
However, starting using it I get a error. Main module uses another one. The root looks like:

- dir

  - main_module.py
  - folder1

    - tech.py
  - folder2

    - conf.ini

The **main_module.py** uses functions from the **tech.py**, whereas tech.py get creds from **conf.ini**. While using main_module.py from the notebook in the dir, that works correctly, but from another dir (with adding `sys.path.append(path_to_dir)`) the **conf.ini** can't be parsed and I catch KeyError. This means that the tech.py doesn't "see" the conf.ini.

The way to conf.ini looks like `./folder2/conf.ini`.

Comment: Relative paths have nothing to do with Python search paths. `./folder2/conf.ini` is a relative path, resolved against whatever the current working directory is.

Comment: @chepner it seems to me you are right. How can you advise me to solve such a problem?

Comment: I would stop using relative paths.

Comment: maybe use absolute path.